# Intra-Package Module Dependencies

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift Package ([you can download here, its a pure Swift markdown implementation](https://github.com/SwiftStudies/SmarkDown)) that has two modules, one a library and the second an executable. Running `swift build` will correctly figure out to build the library, then builds the executable, but fails when it tries to link with the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"__TFE9SmarkDownSSg8markdownSS", referenced from:
  _main in main.swift.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Of course the referenced symbol is the method (or in this case property) I am trying to use (an extension to String).

I guess the question is: is there anything specific that must be done for modules *within* a package to ensure that they are linked together?

Comment: It works fine for me, I don't see any error. Can you please provide more detailed steps.

Comment: 1- Make sure you are using latest Snapshot from https://swift.org/download/#latest-development-snapshots

2 - make sure you setup path correctly. Follow steps from 
https://swift.org/download/#apple-platforms
https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager#installing

Comment: I have the latest snap-shot... also struggling with dependencies do I need to update git?

Comment: what do you mean " also struggling with dependencies do I need to update git" ?

Comment: I should add as another question... when it tries to clone the dependency it does the clone, but then borks with Unknown option: -C, /usr/local/bin/git clone --recursive --depth 10 https://github.com/SwiftStudies/Duration.git /Users/main/Documents/Code/Swift/SPM/Packages/SmarkDown/Packages/Duration

Comment: I can compile your project. It's probably an error with Swift setup on you pc. Check your PATH.

Comment: Well it's good to know it's working for you! My path is right, and swift --version is reporting the correct version... Very strange.

Comment: my PATH setup

export PATH=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin:"${PATH}"

export TOOLCHAINS=swift
export SWIFT_EXEC=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc

Comment: Ah, I haven't done the second export, I wonder if that's the issue? I have just had a reply from an Apple dev that they require git 2.0 (XCode installs 1.8.4) or better. Do you know of the best way to upgrade git on the Mac without upsetting XCode.... I know it sounds unrelated but I can't validate your suggestion as right until I can get the thing to build again!

Comment: brew install git, or
brew upgrade git

Comment: brilliant... do you want to add your SWIFT_EXEC as an answer... as that solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've check your project and it compiles for me.
Here are few things to check:

**1.** Follow Install instructions from [Swift.or](https://swift.org/download/)
**2.** Setup you PATH.

```
export PATH=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin:"${PATH}"  
export TOOLCHAINS=swift   
export SWIFT_EXEC=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
```

**3.** Make sure you use git 2.0 or higher.

```
git --version
```

Comment: It was the SWIFT_EXEC and git 1.8.4 installed by XCode that were the problems. Thank you for your help!